# JWS client to write a file to lib/ext

Tags: java, security, jnlp, java-web-start

Is it possible (maybe using Java security) for a Web Start application to write a file into `java.home\lib\ext` on the client's Windows XP?

I need this regardless of the user credentials as defined by Windows.

Comment: That would be a significant security hole if you could. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Can you do it from the command line? If so, do it the same way using a trusted JWS app.  If not, then no.

Comment: BTW - `java.home\lib\ext`  ***Don't put anything there.***  Sun even advised against that, and the information has not changed since the changeover to Oracle.

Comment: ok, assuming I am creating the file into a different directory (in the  current user home folder) can I rewrite the java.ext.dirs for the client variable to include the new folder?

Comment: 1) Add @PersonName to notify someone of a new comment. 2) Don't stuff about with the `/lib/ext/` ***or*** the property that points to it.  Does it not occur to you that trying to 'cheat' some old, good advice is bound for failure, and that it might be best to reveal what it is you actually want to achieve in terms of an application feature?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible - while you can give the permission to escape the sandbox to a signed web start java app,this will run with the windows user privileges, which is not necessarily in the "administrators" group.